# Knowing how many records inside a query in a project

Tags: sql, peoplesoft, peoplecode

So I have this homework wherein if a PeopleSoft project has a query in it, I try to see how many records are inside this query for performance reason.

I tried going through meta table but I can't seem to find any record that stores this information, or might have miss it.

I have tried some meta table but the closes I got is PSRECDEFN which only has a field for field count.

Does anyone have any experience or idea how to do such task?

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every item added to an Application Designer project is stored in `PSPROJECTITEM`. The `OBJECTTTYPE` indicates what kind of definition it refers to. `OBJECTTYPE 10` is for Query definitions.

The records used by a query are stored in `PSQRYRECORD`. If you need information about fields, use `PSQRYFIELD` (also has record names).

Joining these 2 tables will meet your requirement:

```
SELECT A.PROJECTNAME, A.OBJECTVALUE1 "QUERY", COUNT( DISTINCT B.RECNAME) "RECORDS IN QUERY"
FROM PSPROJECTITEM A, PSQRYRECORD B
WHERE A.PROJECTNAME = :1
    AND A.OBJECTTYPE = 10
    AND B.QRYNAME = A.OBJECTVALUE1
GROUP BY  A.PROJECTNAME, A.OBJECTVALUE1;
```

There is clear and categorized list of PeopleTools (meta) tables available at [digitaleagle](https://psst0101.digitaleagle.net/peopletools-tables/) (no affiliation).

Comment: hey man do you know how to determine if the query in PSPROJECTITEM is distinct?